# SDL Web 8.5 Publishing getting failed due to no items found for WebDAV URL while rendering

Tags: dxa, publishing, web8.5

We have recently installed SDL Web 8.5 on Windows Server 2016 and configured DXA 2.0 CTP top of it. While publishing any Page from Example Site we are getting below error:

> An error occurred while rendering Page '020 Image Library' (tcm:5-302-64)
>   No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/400%20Example%20Site/Home/_System/include/header.tpg.

```
Component: Templating
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri, LoadFlags loadFlags)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Data.DefaultModelBuilder.AddIncludePageRegions(IDictionary`2 regionModels, PageTemplate pageTemplate)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Data.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildPageModel(PageModelData& pageModelData, Page page)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Data.DataModelBuilderPipeline.CreatePageModel(Page page)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.GeneratePageModel.Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.GeneratePageModel.Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)
   at Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine __engine, Package __package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)
```

I have run DXA import script in below order:

1. Created Topology Types

   ```
   \ttm-prepare.ps1 -stagingWebsiteBaseUrls "http://staging01.mycompany.com" -liveWebsiteBaseUrls "live01.mycompany.com"
   ```
2. Imported all Publication into CMS

   ```
   .\cms -import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "http://10.0.0.82:80"
   ```
3. specify the Rights and Permissions for the default User Groups

   ```
   .\cms-import.ps1 -importType rights-permissions -cmsUrl "http://10.0.0.82:80/"
   ```

[image]

Comment: Does that page actually exist? did you miss/skip something when installing/content porting DXA? `400 Example Site/Home/_System/include/header.tpg`

Comment: @NunoLinhares i have followed the instruction from documentation and all  command run successfully without any error

Comment: Same question as Nuno has, so can you please **edit** your question and provide details on if the mentioned include Page is actually there in your CMS, possibly what import scripts you ran and what Publications have been imported etc.?

Comment: According to the error, that page does not exist. Can you please verify if on publication "400 Example Site", under Home/_System/include/, is there a page named "Header"?

Comment: @NunoLinhares I have checked the Header page is exist inside CMS in this path `Home/_System/include/` and I also published this Page

Comment: The stack trace of the error points to https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/DXA_2.0_CTP_2_Release/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Data/DefaultModelBuilder.cs#L291 which indeed seems to indicate that the WebDAV URL `/webdav/"400 Example Site/Home/_System/include/header.tpg` cannot be resolved to a TCM URI. So if you are absolutely sure that this item does exist, there seems to be something wrong in your CM server.

Comment: Did someone perhaps change the "WebDAV URL prefix" setting under "General settings" (in the SDL Web Content Manager Configuration snapin)?

Comment: @PeterKjaer The setting did not change it has the default value /webdav

Comment: @BartKoopman  Webdav is working fine when i change the Header Page Name  to lower case "header" Webdav able to resolve the TcmURI.i did same for Footer Page also.

Comment: The name for the WebDAV URL should be lowercase indeed, as it points to the filename of the Page, the Title of the Page should not have any influence.

Comment: Well... more than that, WebDav on IIS should be case insensitive. I think that's probably the root issue here. If I look in my system, this page's webdav Url does start with a capital H but I never had the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

The Webdav URL is trying to access the Header Page with lower case `header` but inside CMS Header Page is imported as `Header` since WebDAV is case sensitive the WebDAV was not able to get the TCMURI and throwing exception. After changing the Page Name to lower case in CMS pages get published successfully. We have to do same for other Pages also  inside `Home/_System/include` Structure Group.

Comment: This is a bit of a strange conclusion, the Page filename is imported as lowercase and that is what is used by WebDAV. The Page title should not be influencing the WebDAV URL. What you imported is exactly how DXA was developed and is working for everybody else, so I'm glad you have it working, but it seems there is something fishy in your Web 8.5 environment that you require these changes.

Comment: @BartKoopman i took screenshot while importing DXA. It is showing Pages are Updated with uppercase.

Comment: That is showing a Page Title, the Page Filename is lowercase (check it for yourself), and maybe I'm wrong about WebDAV using Page filename (not even sure if WebDAV is actually supposed to be case sensitive since its running on Windows/IIS). Anyways, as mentioned, what you are importing comes from a tested setup, it works on several environments tested on Web 8, Web 8.5 and Web Cloud, so it is at the least strange that it doesn't work on your environment and does on everybody else's.

Comment: @BartKoopman i have confirmed using different cms server that the WebDAV URL contains page name not the file name of the page and it is case sensitive