# No View Model registered for View 'Core:Region:header'

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0

We are getting 500 error while setting up dxa 2.0 dot net website.

```
ERROR - No View Model registered for View 'Core:Region:header'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Core' area registration.
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No View Model registered for View 'Core:Region:header'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Core' area registration.
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Models.ModelTypeRegistry.GetViewModelType(MvcData viewData) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Common\Models\ModelTypeRegistry.cs:line 114
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultModelBuilderR2.CreateRegionModel(RegionModelData regionModelData, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultModelBuilderR2.cs:line 666
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultModelBuilderR2.BuildPageModel(PageModel& pageModel, PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultModelBuilderR2.cs:line 92
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineR2.CreatePageModelInternal(PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\ModelBuilderPipelineR2.cs:line 215
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineR2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreatePageModel>b__0() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\ModelBuilderPipelineR2.cs:line 125
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 65
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineR2.CreatePageModel(PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\ModelBuilderPipelineR2.cs:line 120
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 83
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.R2Mapping.DefaultContentProviderR2.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\R2Mapping\DefaultContentProviderR2.cs:line 41
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 44
```

The view Header.cshtml is exist inside \Areas\Core\Views\Region

Comment: check for ViewModel used with Header.

Answer (score 1):

It is searching a "header" Region, with lowercase, and maybe you have changed the name of the header Page. The Region is registered with uppercase "**Header**".

I don't test this new version myself, but in previous ones, the **Page Name** will be used as the **Region Name** and qualified view name.

Comment: yes i have changed the Header page title to lower case.if i make it uppercase i m not able to publish the Header page and getting webdav url not found error.

Comment: The Page Name, must be Uppercase, can you post the publishing errors you get when you put it uppercase?. I don't know where this webdav reference may come from.

Comment: i already posted a question about publishing error please check this link https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18159/sdl-web-8-5-publishing-getting-failed-due-to-no-items-found-for-webdav-url-while